# How to modify datarow itemarray value?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I'm looking for best way modify `DataRow`(ItemArray)

My code

```
if (DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{

                foreach (DataRow item in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if(item.ItemArray[4].ToString().Equals("0"))
                    {
                        item.ItemArray[4] = "USER";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.ItemArray[4] = "Administrator";
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);

                }

            }
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

but `item.ItemArray[4]` does not change.

Even I've seen a related question that doesn't need to me. Please let me know how to do possible way.

Comment: Did you debug your code line by line and see what is going on? You try to change your collection while you iterate it?

Comment: Please rename `item` to `row`. What is `dt`? You can't add a row of one table to another table. Please fix formatting, it is rather misleading now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding a new row to an `DataTable` please follow this pattern:

```
DataTable dt = ...
DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
// populate newRow here
dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Comment: how populate newRow? modify ItemArray not possiblle ?